# The difference between "d0mY" and 'dmY" in parse_date_ time function of lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

can anyone explain the difference between the outputs of the following two lines of code using the `parse_date_time()`?

```
library(lubridate)
short_dates <- c("11 December 1282", "May 1372", "1253")
parse_date_time(short_dates, orders = c("dOmY", "OmY", "Y"))
parse_date_time(short_dates, orders = c("dmY", "mY", "Y"))
```

both `parse_date_time()` outputs are the same, but I don't know if they are different under the hood.

```
[1] "1282-12-11 UTC" "1372-05-01 UTC" "1253-01-01 UTC"
```

Can anyone explain the advantage of using one format over the other?

Comment: `parse_date_time` is guessing the format in the background, and subsequently ignoring invalid formats like `"dOmY"`.  If you force it to use the formats you specify with `parse_date_time(short_dates, orders = c("dOmY", "OmY", "Y"), exact = TRUE)` the result will be `[1] NA NA NA`.  Use `dmY`, `mY`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I saw `parse_date_time(short_date, orders = c("d0mY", "0mY", "Y"))` in a DataCamp course by Charlotte Wickham. I guess they made an error.